# MKMapView Overlay in IOS6

Tags: ios, xcode, mkmapview, mapkit, mkoverlay

Am adding custom overlays to MKMapView and need to clear the map content before adding overlay (i.e when zoomed or panned default map should be invisible)
Something similar to "canReplaceMapContent" in IOS7 and later.

Is there any method to perform this action in IOS6?

Thanks in advance.,

Answer (score 0):

You method below:

```
- (void) removeMapOverlay {
    [self.mapView removeOverlays:[self.mapView overlays]];

    NSMutableArray *tempArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self.mapView annotations]];
    if ([tempArray containsObject:[MKUserLocation class]]) {
        [tempArray removeObject:[MKUserLocation class]];
    }

    NSArray *annotationArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:tempArray];
    tempArray = nil;
    [self.mapView removeAnnotations:annotationArray];
}
```

**Edit:**

When you pinch/zoom or pan in the map. There are two delegate methods are available you can use to check map is loading or not?

```
- (void)mapViewWillStartLoadingMap:(MKMapView *)mapView {
    NSLog(@"loading...");
}

- (void)mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap:(MKMapView *)mapView {
    NSLog(@"Map loaded...");
}
```

What i suggest you to use above two methods. Create a bool variable or some means not to load annotations when zoom. How ever i'll keep update if there is other simple way to do it.

Comment: Thanks for responding, but this removes all the custom overlays that added to mkmapview but not the map from mkmapview

Comment: If you want to remove map from MkMapView, Then where you show custom overlays?

Comment: in IOS7, if we use this flag (canReplaceMapContent) we cannot see map before adding overlay or when zoomed or panned. I was trying to achieve this for IOS6 but not able to figure.

Comment: @KrishnaChaitanyaBandaru Check edit answer. It may help you. I'll edit answer if there is more easy way to do this.

Comment: I tried this but still i was able to see map. It seems there is no possibility to make mkmapview stop loading its own tiles

Comment: No. You can not override default map tiles loading. Yes you can control your custom overlays loading.

Answer (score 0):

You could draw a custom, opaque overlay on top of Apple's maps, but there is still a very slight chance that you will see the map beneath from time to time. I'd recommend an alternative, open source toolset that you can control like [Mapbox](http://mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk) for complete control.